# mySQL 'invalid column' error

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to insert a relationship in table 'products_to_categories' when the condition is met in the 'products' table (master_categories_id = 500) My guess is because my SELECT statement should be a JOIN?

```
table: products_to_categories
columns: products_id, categories_id

table: products
columns: products_id, master_categories_id

INSERT INTO products_to_categories (products_id, categories_id)  
SELECT products.products_id, 500 FROM products  
WHERE products.master_categories_id=500 HAVING count(categories_id) < 1;
```

error returned: `categories_id is an invalid column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few ways:

```
SELECT products.products_id, 500, products.categories_id FROM products
WHERE products.master_categories_id=500 HAVING count(categories_id) < 1;
```

Or

```
SELECT products.products_id, 500, count(products.categories_id) as cat_count FROM products
WHERE products.master_categories_id=500 HAVING cat_count < 1;
```

Comment: yeah i tried that, categories_id isn't in the 'products' table. Which is why I am guessing I need to rewrite with a JOIN. or can you simply say products_to_categories.categories_id in the SELECT?

Comment: Here's my best guess at it, forgive me, usually I just use PHP to handle this kind of thing, trying to get more comfy with more advanced querys to avoid script writing.

INSERT INTO products_to_categories (products_id, categories_id)
SELECT products.products_id, products.master_categories_id, products_to_categories.categories_id
INNER JOIN products ON products.products_id=products_to_categories.products_id
FROM products WHERE products.master_categories_id=500 HAVING count(categories_id) < 1;

Comment: Your from is in the wrong place and I added table aliases: SELECT p.products_id, p.master_categories_id, ptc.categories_id FROM products_to_categories ptc INNER JOIN products p ON p.products_id=ptc.products_id WHERE p.master_categories_id=500 HAVING count(ptc.categories_id) < 1;

Comment: that got it. Had the FROM in the wrong spot and too many columns selected. after clearing those up it worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `categories_id` column needs to be available in one of the tables in your `SELECT`. In this case, only `products` is there, so the only valid columns are `products_id` or `master_categories_id`.